# onscreen annotation software for Ubuntu 16.04 with i3wm?

Tags: i3-wm, annotation

I want to do screen annotation for recording a video lecture. That is to draw shapes and markings on top of other programs while recording.

I've been searching the whole day but not found a working one. I tried `gromit-mpx`, `ardesia` from Ubuntu's repository. Both of them works for compiz-based window manager, and therefore do not work with i3wm out of the box. I got `gromit-mpx` to start but that's all. The `Annoation` plugin of compiz is also mentioned by others for annotation. I haven't tried it. It seems that I have only only one to get the screen annotation work: switch to non-i3 window manager( i.e. Gnome). But I want to avoid that because I love i3 so much :) So how do you guys do screen annotation in a i3wm session?

Answer (score 5):

I use xmonad rather than i3, but perhaps it's a similar solution:

I was able to get it working with `gromit-mpx` by specifying a key that I was able to type, in this case F9:

```
gromit-mpx --key "F9"
```

Then pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>, my cursor changed to a crosshair, and I was able to annotate my screen; right click acts as an eraser.

Screenshot of gromit-mpx successfully annotating on xmonad:

[image]

Comment: gromit-mpx is nice, but it has no "textbox"-feature, what I really would like to have (pylote doesnt do it right and I can't get ardesia or compiz working  on my Deb 9 )

Comment: @eli Did you find any other solutions for i3wm + textbox + drawing?

Comment: @pagliuca sorry, I didn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

I use Flameshot, which is a screen capture tool. I launch it over the whole screen using a bash script. The best solution so far for me. Gromit is very limited.

> [image: Annotation screenshot]

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

WIDTH=$(xrandr --query | grep ' connected' | cut -d' ' -f 3 | cut -d'x' -f 1)
HEIGHT=$(xrandr --query | grep ' connected' | cut -d'x' -f 2 | cut -d'+' -f 1)
XTARGET=`expr $WIDTH / 2 - 330`
YTARGET=`expr $HEIGHT - 25`

# Launch the snapshot gui
flameshot gui && sleep 0.07

# Save the current mouse location
eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)

# Move the mouse to the top left corner and drag it to to the right bottom corner
xdotool mousemove 0 0
xdotool mousedown 1 # pres and hold
xdotool mousemove ${WIDTH} ${HEIGHT}
xdotool mouseup 1 # release click
sleep 0.07

# Click on pen tool
xdotool mousemove ${XTARGET} ${YTARGET} click 1

# Restore mouse to previous location
xdotool mousemove ${X} ${Y}%
```